# How to destructure a QML rect?

Tags: qml

I have a `rect` to save / restore window positions.

```
import QtCore
import QtQml
import QtQuick.Controls

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true

    Component.onCompleted: {
        // Here's what I tried so far:
        // [window.x, window.y, window.width, window.height] = settings.coords;
        // { window.x, window.y,  window.width, window.height } = settings.coords;
    }

    Settings {
        id: settings
        property rect coords
    }
}
```

I know I can manually assign each attribute, but that's *boring*.

Answer (score 0):

To make the object destructuring assignment work with `settings.coords`:

- The left-hand side needs to be an object with the keys well defined

  - i.e. this rules out your first-attempt because your left-hand side was an array when it should be an object
  - your second attempt is ruled out because your left-hand side isn't quite a valid object, it needs to be `{x:window.x,y:window.y,width:window.width,height:window.height}` or `{x,y,width,height}` not `{window.x,window.y,window.width,window.height}`
- Parenthesis/brackets are required, so, I had to encase the entire assignment inside them
- When the destructuring occurs inside the `window` scope, we can explicitly omit the `window.` prefix

In other words, the solution is:

```js
({x:window.x,y:window.y,width:window.width,height:window.height} = settings.coords);
```

or even:

```js
({x,y,width,height} = settings.coords);
```

Because you're using QML, we can make use of a dummy declarative property binding to contain this destructuring assignment:

```
property rect dummy: ({x,y,width,height} = settings.coords)
```

I have mocked up [an online sample](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAACBnicjVDLisMwDLznK0RPLQSnj5uXPSz9gG36B20sEu8mVrBV0lDy77VJnaYLhR2Q0Qg8M5JuWrIMOecXXfwm+oWKPRm2VLvkcCoRbgl4HLHgkynryAO0ktBpo6ibRgXVZCUsLKrFNGwttWi5B+tFQF2appcww/J2Tfu004qrtEJdVjzAJzhk1qZ0oiCyyq0gy+DLuA4t7CbpPfnoBg0LMqGvkdGnemYMyDLvIMekwlvF9uEZ6TxAnL2P8zHLs/lj98+N5hLbSWJInm/O3+efcLTXo0ehNxce5aX/LQJfbtbrNNR2rNXDYLgDUKGa7g==)

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: In your 2nd code, how will the properties get applied to `window`? It looks like new variables are being created. JS syntax is definitely weird.

Comment: It is explained by scope. If the function/event is declared in the scope of `window` then window scope is implicit and may be omitted.

Comment: Did you try the code snippet? All 3 answers are present. You can uncomment any to try them out.